# I want to use Infocardapi.dll in Delphi/WIN32 but would like a header file for it

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-2007, cardspace

Microsoft has this nice little feature called CardSpace. This is a [Microsoft implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163615.aspx) of [InfoCards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Card). Microsoft has a [nice document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/c/3/6c3c2ba2-e5f0-4fe3-be7f-c5dcb86af6de/infocard-guide-beta2-published.pdf) which explains how it can be used, which is useful. And doing a Google search doesn't provide me many useful answers but it does provide an enormous amount of noise. (Mostly because people wonder what it is or sites offering this DLL as some kind of download. The latter is suspicious since it's just part of Windows Vista and .NET 3.0 and higher.)

Basically, I need to call all functionality from this DLL within Delphi 2007. If there's a C++ header for this DLL then I can convert it. Or maybe some other information about it's functions, parameters, datatypes and whatever more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an InfoCard.h file included with Microsoft's [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4377F86D-C913-4B5C-B87E-EF72E5B4E065&displaylang=en) which should be what you need. Bit of a hefty download for a single file if you don't already have it - you might be better visiting the MSDN reference for the [CardSpace API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702727.aspx) and getting the info from there.

Comment: Found it! :-) I have the SDK already installed but failed to find it.